# Precise drag and drop into textarea or editable content with displaying caret when dragging

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I have a list of items and I want to drag them and placed in textarea or content editable div element. I'm wondering if it's possible to display caret between each character in the text during dragging element. This is the same effect like the MS Word has:
[image]

In this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y131d4wm/2/) I can drag element and drop on textarea but text is added at the end, but I want to have active caret to decide when drop element.

```
    $("#divFields li").draggable({
    helper: "clone"
});

$("#divDroppedFields").droppable({
    accept: "#divFields li",
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        var messageValue = $("#txtMessageFields").val();            
        messageValue = messageValue + ' #' + ui.draggable.text() + '! ';
        $(this).find('#txtMessageFields').val(messageValue);
    }
});
```

Comment: I help you but give me your jsfiddle link

Comment: Fiddle available is here: http://jsfiddle.net/y131d4wm/2/ Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Having the same challange - I'm working on it right now. A trick (I'm testing at the moment) will be to replace the text area with a div, where every letter is an html node as well. this way you could detect which node it was dropped on. and insert it there and convert back.